# Java Regex pattern to extract a url from a response string using Pattern and Matcher

Tags: java, regex

from the following response string I want to extract the the http url .

```
throw 'allowScriptTagRemoting is false.';
//#AWR-INSERT
//#AWR-REPLY
dwr.engine._remoteHandleCallback('2','0',\"https://azqa.ms.tors.com/mediaservice/api/v2/media/showme_cf17c4eb_8368_4862_a97a_a5a435849e32/NG_LANDING/status?token=96389580449a866d787fcc1fbb8dac8fa893d8378a9d0a9b28a6569f29acb97cd85292dec28c2a3dad7c97dda33140a3f34fe7929e2646714a9a183cc58f8f9c,7400505368697056934,1683592125,2");
```

I tried the following code using Pattern and Matcher:

```
 public static  String extractUrl(String str){
            String url= "";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("https?:\\S+[^\");]");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
            if(matcher.find()) {
                url = matcher.group(0);
                System.out.println("Media services URl is :\n "+ url);
                log.info("Media services URl is :\n {}", url);
            }
                return url;
   }
```

However, I see the `");` getting appended to the `url`. What am I missing here? , shouldn't the `[^\");]` exclude the same.

[on : regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WojlZd/1)

Comment: Probably there's a newline on the end of the string which is matching `[^\");]`. Why not just use `https?:[^\");]+`

Comment: You don't need all the code: [It can be done in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76206073/256196).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a newline at the end of the string. Since `\S+` is greedy, it matches all the characters up to there, leaving the newline for `[^"\);]`.

You could directly use `https?:[^"\);\s]+` instead, which matches a sequence of consecutive characters that are not part of the excluded ones.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for something simpler:

```
"https?://[^\"]+"
```

(see [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/cKAW6wlFISObVa))

which matches everything up to, but not including, the next `"`.

"//" added to the protocol for tighter match.

---

By the way, you don't need all that code. This returns the url, or blank if no url found, all in one line of code:

```
public static  String extractUrl(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("(?s).*?(?=http)([^\"]+).*|.*", "$1");
}
```

See [live java demo](https://ideone.com/ImmId5).

The extra `|.*` at the end handles the "no url" scenario as a fallback in case the first regex fails to match, in which case group 1 will be blank.